How do I perform a smear between two dataframes in python/pandas?
I have two dataframes and I need to perform a smear (if that is what it's generally called). Basically the first one is smaller (5 million rows) and the other is 40 million rows. I want to add the first value of dataframe 1 to the first 8 values of dataset 2, the second from dataframe 1 to the second set of 8 in dataframe 2 and so on.
For example:
Dataset 1:



Category
Value




1
3


2
5


3
7



Dataset 2:



Category
Value




1
6


1
3


1
7


2
2


2
8


2
1


3
4


3
0


3
9



And I want it to look like
Result:



Category
Value




1
9


1
6


1
10


2
7


2
13


2
6


3
11


3
7


3
16



Sorry, if my formatting isn't very good, I'm not too used to SO and couldn't a question to similar to mine.
I have attempted to use apply_smearing, but not sure if that is even what I should be, and it only resulted in errors. I'll come back to update this post in a bit with the actual code I tried.

If you want to add the values based on the dataframes sizes, regardless of the values in column 'Category', you can use numpy.repeat.
df2["Value"] += np.repeat(df1["Value"].values, len(df2) // len(df1))

If you want to add based on the values in 'Category', you can use pandas.DataFrame.map:
df2["Value"] += df2["Category"].map(df1.set_index("Category")["Value"])

Both will output:
   Category  Value
0         1      9
1         1      6
2         1     10
3         2      7
4         2     13
5         2      6
6         3     11
7         3      7
8         3     16


No need to convert to dict, df2['Value'] += df2['Category'].map(df1.set_index('Category')['Value']) is enough

Thank you for the help! However, when I try that approach, I get a value error of "ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (39232741,) (44669674,). I'm not really sure if I'm missing something or not.

@babyface Hard to tell, as the error doesn't happen with the example data. You can create a minimal reproducible example that reproduces the error and edit your question to include it, or create a new question.
